# Protractor .ts: How do I proceed without failures, whether something appears or not, using .then(), .catch()?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to proceed through a dialog that may or may not appear. Here's a function:

When I run this in an it block in Jasmine/Protractor AND the catch gets run..."FALSE"...

Jasmine completes the test, then fails with "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL"

I can only assume this is because Jasmine/Protractor are a little too smart. I am looking for the equivalent, basically, of Java Webdriver - try/catch the wait and continue merrily on my way.

Note that when the button does appear, the test passes no problem. "TRUE"

```
let okButton: ElementFinder = element(by.buttonText("OK"));
await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(okButton)).then(() => {
    console.log("TRUE");
    okButton.click();
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("FALSE");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this

```js
describe("async function", function() {
  it("should not fail", async function(): Promise < any > {
    const okButton: ElementFinder = element(by.buttonText("OK"));

    try {
      await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(okButton));
      console.log("TRUE");
      await okButton.click();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("FALSE");
    }
  });
});
```

See also [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html) and the [protractor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually tried this to begin with, then abandoned it after I was still getting Timeout errors. However, after trying again, I think I'm discovering that this piece of code may not have been the source of the Timeout error. That is, that this is a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `done` callback:

e.g.

```
it('handles a promise', done => {
   promise
      .then(result => expect(result).toEqual(expected))
      .catch(error => expect(error).toBeUndefined())
      .finally(done)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your very useful gitbook, @basarat. Since this is a function being called by a beforeAll, should I plan on doing functionName().finally(done) in the beforeAll? I had been doing done() at the bottom of the code block...